# Login with facebook button not being displayed

Tags: plugins, wordpress

Using Ultimate Facebook plugin with wordpress. I have added the connect shortcode to my page but I just get an image avatar and not the normal login button.

Comment: if functionality working you can change it by css

Comment: Thanks but is login button not the default for the short code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort code is normally used to call function and  function  have code and in that you can add css  also you can add classes by jquery if dont want to go inside the exact code .

Comment: but the actual funtionality of the the button is not working, its just an image.